SQL Server Management Studio - 20.2.30.0 - Drag and drop view not found
When creating a new view, using the drag and drop function, a prohibition symbol appears.
I can instead create it by right-clicking and selecting 'Add Table'.
The problem only occurs on certain servers.
For example:

Server 1: All databases allow drag and drop.
Server 2: Drag and drop does not work on any databases.

I have tried reinstalling SSMS and SSEI.
The user has sysadmin permissions.

Don't use the designer; that's the real solution. Learn the T-SQL; write the T-SQL. That designer probably hasn't been updated since 1997.

You can report it to Microsoft as a bug here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0
